# How get information from three different tables at once?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have following models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start_slot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    end_slot = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Reservation(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_slot = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_reservation = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} for device: {} by {}.".format(self.time_slot, self.date_of_reservation, self.device, self.user)


class ForbiddenSlot(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_slot = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time_slot)
```

This is simple reservation system. I have problem to understand how create query for three different tables. 
I want get all TimeSlots which are not set in ForbiddenSlot and Reservation for given Device name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work, but I think it will and is definitely worth a shot.

```py
TimeSlot.objects.filter(
    forbiddenslot__isnull=True,
    reservation__device__name='Device Name',
)
```

It's not necessarily the easiest thing for me to wrap my head around, but not only does `TimeSlot` have access to `.forbiddenslot_set`, it also can filter by `forbiddenslot`. The same goes for `reservation`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess changing the structure of your models will be much better, like deleting the model `ForbiddenSlot` and replacing it with a flag on the reservation model, then you can select all TimeSlots from the reservation model where the forbidden flag is False, like:
`reservations = Reservation.objects.only('time_slot').filter(device__name=name_of_the_device,forbidden=False)` where `forbidden` is a boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

Using select_related() will pre-populate the appropriate attributes:

```
Model.objects.select_related()
```